# The footer of the screen flow has spaces around window

Tags: visual-workflow, administration, screen-flow, flowscreen, flow-screen-component

Why The footer of the screen flow has spaces around window?

[image]

the screen flow runs from the button and does not wrapped to any lightning component

when I investigated it through Dev tool, I noticed that:

[image]

Flow fields (including **footer** section) are wrapped around `article` tag that has `slds-p-around--medium` that's causing this behavior.

Also, I noticed that flow is using `flowruntime-flow` and `flowruntime-lwc-body` tags.

Is this padding result of some kind of update from Salesforce regarding the flow?